# Unable to access json file from lambda function Go

Tags: json, go, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function with GoLang, when I import config.json file on my local it works. But when deployed on lambda(using GH actions), it get:

> opening config file open /var/task/config.json: no such file or
> directory

file structure are as follows:

```
project
├── subfolder
│  ├── subfolder
│  │  ├── main.go
│  │  └── config.json
```

reading file as follows:

```
pwd, _ := os.Getwd()
var config_path string = path.Join(pwd) + "/config.json"
configFile, err := os.Open(config_path)
```

Also tried

```
configFile, err := os.Open("config.json")
```

Comment: Embed your config.

Answer (score 2):

From the path in the error `/var/task/config.json` it looks like you need to change directory into `project/subfolder/subfolder` first or add that piece of the path to your `config_path`.

Also, I think you want to join paths like this

```
var config_path string = path.Join(pwd, "project", "subfolder", "subfolder" "config.json")
```